# Import Database schema using Draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com) there is a great beta feature called 'Automated ERD Import' where you can import all tables, columns, constraints etc from a database. This is super useful as you can quickly build ERDs within minutes without manually creating any entities.

At my workplace we are now using [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) so I am wondering if there is an equivalent or similar feature that can help me in avoiding manually creating entities.

I've had a look through the Draw.io online user manual but haven't been able to find anything useful. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

draw.io has a generic SQL import under the Arrange->Insert->SQL menu:

[image: Insert SQL menu option in draw.io]

Copy and paste your SQL commands in to the dialog and press insert:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to edit the design? (To have the Datatype in a seperate column from the name)

Comment: Sadly doesn't import/infer foreign key relationships.

Answer (score 4):

Since August 2015 you can import your Lucidchart in Draw.io.
According to [this](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000063693-import-lucidchart-diagrams-into-diagrams-net/Gliffy+and+Lucidchart+importing) explanation you have to do the following:

1. Save your ERD as a Gliffy JSON format
2. Import it in Draw.io throug: File -> Import from ...

Maybe when the ERD is imported it also automatically makes the columns, constraints and eventually tables.

Comment: @Thomas The Tank Engine, is any native support for relationships planned? Thanks!